# Why doesn't overriding a View Controller's navigationItem seem to do anything?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I've now looked at the TONS of posts that are about **removing the text from the back button on a UINavigationBar**.  They don't seem to work anymore (iOS 10+).  And even if they did, they don't "smell correct"...

My question is, why doesn't this work?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private var _navItem: UINavigationItem? = nil
    override var navigationItem: UINavigationItem {
        if _navItem == nil {
            let item = super.navigationItem
            let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            backBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
            backBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
            item.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
            _navItem = item
        }
        return _navItem!
    }
    //...
}
```

I would expect to see a button that has clear text, but I see the title of the previous view controller as the back button text.

Do I need to subclass `UINavigationController`? or mess around with `UINavigationBarDelegate`?

Comment: You need to do this on the "previous view controller" not the one that you see the back button on.

Comment: That's the answer!

Comment: Allen is right but you can also achieve this on same controller.

Comment: let me share my solution in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely common point of confusion, since the API is a bit counterintuitive on its face. The [documentation that explains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem) it is a little convoluted as well

> When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the navigation bar from this navigation item. When this property is nil, the navigation item uses the value in its title property to create an appropriate back button.

Basically, you need to do this on the "previous view controller" not the one that you see the back button on.

Though I'm not sure what your overall goals are, to do it "app wide", you have a couple options.

- Put this into some sort of global base view controller class for your entire project. This is particularly cumbersome if you want to have different base classes for different parts of your apps, and of course when dealing with different types of system controllers.
- UIAppearance methods, which have the downside (or upside?) of affecting every single bar button item, including the back button. This solution is generally too broad, though it is undeniably global.

  ```
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
  ```
- Provide a custom left bar button item on the top view controller that you want the back button on. This solution again requires a base class of sorts, or good 'ol copy-pasta. And of course, loosing the ability to have the system back chevron provided for you. The alternative being an extension (Gabriel's answer provides a lovely example of that).

Everything has tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, wanted to use an icon without text, and the text kept showing up. After a long search and a lot of trying, I had to resort to creating a custom button and setting it as the leftBarButtonItem.
Here's the relevant code:

```
protocol CustomBackButton {
    func configureBackButton()
    func removeBackButton()
}

extension CustomBackButton where Self: UIViewController {
    func configureBackButton() {
        let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        backButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "backIconButton"), for: .normal)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchBackButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .lightGray
    }

    func removeBackButton() {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }

}

extension UIViewController {
    func didTouchBackButton() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

The removeBackButton() is only used because I have a popup window that shouldn't have a back button so I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Although Allen answer is correct that you need to do this on the "previous view controller" not the one that you see the back button on.

Although you can achieve your goal on same controller as well, here is my solution,

This function will return you `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem  *bbBack = [self overrideBackBarButtonItemWithTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackTapped:)];
```

Implement selector some where in your current controller:

```
- (IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Function:

```
-(UIBarButtonItem*)overrideBackBarButtonItemWithTarget:(nullable id)target action:(nullable SEL)action  {


    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65 , 44)];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 15);//move image to the right
    [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barbuttonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    spacer.width = -15;

    UIViewController *_self = (UIViewController*)target;
    [_self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer,barbuttonBack, nil] animated:NO];

    return barbuttonBack;
}
```

[Navigation back image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLpEY.png)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this solution changes the semantics of which class is "concerned" with the back button. If the "previous view controller" from the answer pushes many different view controllers, each target view controller will need this code.

Comment: Sorry, I won't accept this answer, even though it works for you (for now).  No offense, but it's a total hack for many reasons:  I have to use your back image, you have tons of hard-coded int values in the code (bad style), you're completely working around the existing iOS way of doing things with a back button, AND you haven't even posted how to do this "app wide".  What I missed in all the other answers to this question was that the navigationItem's backButton is in the context of (when I am a back button, not when I am the topViewController on the stack)

Comment: Huh. what is hack in the answer?

Comment: I come up with this solution after trying all others, there are some cases when you need navigations back button custom actions, other solutions will work for you but you will have back button image either with small touch area or having left offset. Actually I implemented this function in my Utilities Class as class function, so i don't rewrite this code in every repeating controller. You just need that one line code to call this function & there is nothing hacks. Choice is your :)

Answer (score 0):

The credit should go to Allen Humphreys, but the question I posted above DOES make sure they would have no text on the back button, but you would have to ensure all your view controllers inherit from this class.

It didn't seem to do anything because I thought that setting the backButton text is for when the view controller itself is the one currently visible on the stack, but what it actually means is "what is the back button title when this view controller is second from the top?"

My question arose because the view controller 'second from the top' did not use this overridden navigationItem.

Comment: If it should, why don't you give it to me ;-)